# Is this a*b = a is semigroup and commutative?

Tags: semigroups

Let S be any nonempty set with the operation a * b = a. Is (S,*) a semigroup? Is it commutative?

I dont know what to do if a * b = merely a. Usually if a * b = anything that have operation i know how to do.
Can anyone show the proof as well? Thanks.

Comment: Definitely not commutative. What happens to $b*a$ when $b\neq a$.

Comment: but (S,*) is semigroup right?

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(S,*)$ is a semigroup but the operation is not commutative. To be a semigroup the operation $*$ must be associative, which it is. Let $a,b,c \in S$ then consider

$$a*(b*c) = a* b = a$$ and $$ (a*b)*c = a*c = a$$
thus $a*(b*c)\equiv(a*b)*c$. It is not commutative however, consider two elements $a,b\in S:a\neq b$. 
$$a*b = a \neq b = b*a.$$

Comment: But if $S$ has just one element, it is a commutative group. A trivial one. Um, *the* trivial one.

Comment: True. An important proviso!

Comment: And if $S$ has no elements, it is a commutative inverse semigroup.